# Porque la funcion trim() no me elimina los espacios sobrantes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una validación de textos, donde ingrese el siguiente testo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento aplicarle `.trim()`, para eliminar esos espacios, me devuelve otra vez el texto, por lo cual no se bien si tengo que aplicar otra cosa o se esta haciendo mal el `.trim()`

Estoy usando react y javascript.

Comment: Trim elimina los espacios en los extremos, no los que están en medio de la cadena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) elimina los espacios extra situado a ambos extremos de la cadena (al inicio y al final), en tu caso lo que tienes son múltiples espacios consecutivos dentro de la misma, por lo que `trim` no te sirve, no directamente al menos.

Si quieres reemplazar esos espacios por uno solo, puedes usar `replace` y regex, por ejemplo:

```js
let text = "Rol          f1";
let result = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(result)
```

- **\s**: busca coincidencias con cualquier espacio en blanco.
- **+**: cuantificador codicioso, uno o más.
- **/g**: bandera para la búsqueda iterativa en toda la cadena (**g**lobal)

Ten en cuenta que `\s` coincide con cualquier espacio en blanco (***w**hitespace character*), lo que incluye no solo espacios horizontales, también fabulaciones y nuevas lineas. Si no te interesa substituir también estos caracteres, puedes adaptar la expresión, por ejemplo para evitar remplazar los caracteres de nueva linea y retorno de carro:

```js
let text = "Hola\t\t   mundo          \notra linea";
let result = text.replace(/[^\S\n\r]+/g, ' ');
console.log(result)
```

Adicionalmente a `replace` puedes aplicar `trim` si quieres eliminar completamente los espacios de los extremos.

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript, el método `trim()` se utiliza para eliminar los espacios en blanco al principio y al final de una cadena, pero no afecta a los espacios en blanco dentro del texto.
Si quieres eliminar los espacios en blanco dentro del texto, puedes usar el método `replace()` con una expresión regular.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
const content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor   sit amet, consectetur  adipiscing elit.';
const contentWithoutExtraSpaces = content.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

console.log(contentWithoutExtraSpaces);
```

En este caso, la expresión regular /\s+/g coincide con uno o más espacios en blanco y los reemplaza por un solo espacio.

Espero que esto te ayude.